# Return current page on load framework7

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I want to return current page on load. If the user directly lands on that page it should redirect to home page.

Below script works on 'pageInit' but i want to get the current page on load. if the user directly lands on 'email-confirmation' it should redirect to home page.

```
$(document).on('pageInit', function(e){ // it is working on pageInit but I need it in load.
    var page = e.detail.page;
    console.log(page.name);
    if(page.name=="email-confirmation") {
        mainView.router.loadPage('dashboard.html');//home page              
    }           

})
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [preroute](https://framework7.io/docs/init-app.html#example-with-preroute) to manage redirection page, no ?

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thank you @djiggy :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the vanila javascript code to achieve my need. But request to use [preroute](https://framework7.io/docs/init-app.html#example-with-preroute) as suggested by @Djiggy.

```
    var data_attrs = [];
        var data_attr = "";
        $("body").each(function(){
            $(this).find(".page").each(function(){
                attr_value =  $(this).attr('data-page');
                data_attrs.push(attr_value) // returns dashboard and email-confirmation
            });
        });
        console.log(data_attrs);
        if(attr_value[1]=="email-confirmation") {
            mainView.router.loadPage('dashboard.html');//home page              
        }
```